# MSTest from command line

Tags: powershell, mstest

I am trying to run MSTest from command line in powershell.

```
mstest /testcontainer:Common.Tests.dll
```

I am in the project bin/debug folder.  It opens a new command window and the window closes either with no output or output that I can't read, as a result of the window immediately closing.  The test run successfully in Visual Studio and the project builds successfully using MSBuild and in Visual Studio.  I assume that something is breaking but I have no idea how to determine what it could be.

I am using VS 14.0.
I have also tried vstest.console with the same result.

Comment: I just used nunit and added the --wait flag.  I tried all the suggested and it still forks another window and std out seems to be nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way to do that would be:

```
mstest /testcontainer:Common.Tests.dll > result.txt 2>&1
```

that would redirect all output to the result.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the output to a variable and then use it however you wish, like just outputting it to screen...

```
$mstest = Invoke-Expression "mstest /testcontainer:Common.Tests.dll"
Write-Output $mstest
```